# What are the best export settings for Kolor or other pano-stitching software to create 360° videos in Unity?

Tags: post-production, export

I'm using the Autopano Giga 4.4 and Autopano Video Pro 2.6 to stitch and create spherical content, but I've recently moved into wanting to create 360° tours via Unity. I know this is partly a developers question, but if anyone out there can help me with the right specs for exporting a spherical image from Giga to use to create the image for the inside of the sphere on Unity, I'd appreciate it!

Even though experimenting with Premiere and FCPX to edit highlight reels of spherical content, I've had seamless experiences created. For some reason in Unity, the images appear to be stretched around the sphere wrong and it's creates issues on the top and bottom of the image.

Comment: Could you post an image of the bad results you're seeing, and maybe the original pano image?

Comment: I'm not sure of how to post a picture on here, but, I uploaded a screenshot of the results of the stitch in Unity. It's available in my dropbox, thanks for any help, I appreciate it! I've had smooth images in Giga, Pano Video pro, as well as Adobe. I think it's just the encoding that Unity uses for the 360 spherical content... https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i6ywe445qshxyo/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-05%20at%207.28.19%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: That is really odd! I see 2 things that look odd - the geometry of the projection (looks like it was projected onto a very low-res sphere or something), and it also looks like the top (or is it bottom?) of the image was cut off before projecting it. I don't know why those things would happen.

Comment: @user1118321 - that's exactly what I thought too! I figured the sphere was too low of a resolution, that's why the encoding of the video wouldn't allow it to be flat. I definitely am lost as to how to fix it. I've been on the software trying different codecs for about four days, all the same results.

Comment: You might ask over on the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com). They do a lot of Unity development over there and one of them may have run into this before.

Comment: Great idea! I'll go join and ask @user1118321